# Terminal: Help understanding behavior with UTF-8 text

Tags: terminal, unicode, right-to-left

I am trying to understand the following behavior I am observing on my Ubuntu system. Consider the following two files:

```
$ hexdump -C 1.txt
00000000  d9 82 d8 a8 d8 a7 d9 86  d9 8a 5e d9 84 d9 86 d8  |..........^.....|
00000010  b2 d8 a7 d8 b1 5d 31                              |.....]1|
00000017
```

and

```
$ hexdump -C 2.txt
00000000  d9 82 d8 a8 d8 a7 d9 86  d9 8a 5e d9 84 d9 86 d8  |..........^.....|
00000010  b2 d8 a7 d8 b1 5d 20                              |.....] |
00000017
```

We can check there is a single difference:

```
$ cmp 1.txt 2.txt
1.txt 2.txt differ: byte 23, line 1
```

However here is what I see on my side:

```
$ echo $LANG
C.UTF-8
$ cat 1.txt
قباني^لنزار]1
$ cat 2.txt
قباني^لنزار]
```

I really do not understand that behavior. I do not see neither an ALM (ARABIC LETTER MARK) Unicode Character nor a RLM (RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK) in the utf-8 stream. For reference:

- [ALM](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/061c/index.htm) in UTF-8 is `d89c`, while
- [RLM](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200f/index.htm) in UTF-8 is `e2808f`.

Could someone explain the behavior I am seeing ?

For reference:

```
$ head -3 /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
```

and

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: cat is `stupid` so it do nothing but just copying bytes without changing encoding. I assume the rendering engine of your terminal do the job, and I assume using the automatic bidirectional algorithm of Unicode. On one: ` is seen as part of Arabic text (it doesn't have a predefined directionality), but if it is near the `1`, it will take directionality of `1`. I assume you may get different behavious on different terminals (and operating systems). -- Unicode defines the marks to ovverride such default cases (or just to be explicit in case of *stupid* text engine)

Comment: Care to post that as an answer? In particular how to disable that funky behavior in my terminal would be an awsome answer !

Comment: I can guess the reason, but we are in a territory where things are done mostly by *magic* and not *reason*. And I'm surprised of such behaviour (I would expect ESC-sequence marks for terminals), and really curious on how cursor will work on such environment. IIRC from old discussions, terminals should not use Pango (which I assume is changing orders according Unicode, not according terminal), but directly shaping engine

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi neither of your complaints are valid. (1) "_`cat` is stupid_" - actually it's doing exactly what it's defined to do. If you want to use a tool for changing the character set encoding take a look at `iconv`. (2) "_we are in a territory where things are done mostly by magic and not reason_" - not really. Unicode is complex but it's definitely not magic

Comment: malat I don't see the same behaviour here. Debian 12 ("bookworm") with `LANG=C.UTF-8` I get the same as you for `1.txt` (right-aligned on the terminal), but for `2.txt` I get the same as `1.txt` except that the `1` has been replaced with a space. I don't read Arabic but as far as I can tell the strings are otherwise visually identical. As far as `cat` goes, it copies a sequence of bytes from its input to its output without regard to character set or locale, so I think your question is better suited to being asked about your terminal emulator (mine is Cygwin's `mintty`)

Comment: @ChrisDavies: *stupid* in the mantra: *KISS*: *keep things simple and stupid*, so by design. The second part: you are right: Unicode has predictable algorithms, but libraries (stand now) and font supports are not so good, if you look about pango and harfbuz bug reports you see the *magic*. And terminals should not use Pango (and so Unicode text layering). Arabic is in a good shape because... one of the core developer is native on such script. -- And the missing information: such job is done by the terminal emulator: so we should compare with OP terminals: other may be ... better

Comment: You showed us what you see _as text_. If I copy-paste those back to a file and run `hexdump`, I get the same as you. That is, you have simply copy-pasted into your post, you have not rearranged the letters. If you indeed see the same thing in your terminal as in your modern browser then it means that your terminal performs BiDi shuffling just like your browser does; presumably according to the Unicode Bidirecitonal Algorithm (UBA). To understand the vastly different rendering of two barely different strings, you need to study UBA, your question is unrelated to terminals or "stupid" cat.

Comment: Copy-paste your text to https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/bidi.jsp to show a breakdown of what the algorithm does. (Choose "bidi" or "bidi-c" for somewhat different output format.) Set Paragraph Direction to LTR because that's what apparently browsers do in this post as well as your terminal does for you. In some terminals you can get the Paragraph Direction: Auto behavior, if that's what you're looking for. To further guide you how to enable that, we'd need to know what terminal you're using.